# Pasar valor de select obtenido por js a una variable de php en un numero de factura

Tags: php, javascript, html

como dije arriba tengo un numero de factura el cual tiene que llevar el codigo del departamento y lo que quiero es que dependiendo del departamento que se seleccione el numero de factura cambie es decir si selecciono compras el nro de factura sera "COMN1"

Tengo el siguiente codigo que obtiene el dato por js sin embargo no se como enviar esa variable dinamica a mi codigo de generar numero

```
<script> $(function(){
$(document).on('change','#codd',function(){ //detectamos el evento change
  var value = $(this).val();//sacamos el valor del select
  $('#dep').val(value);//le agregamos el valor al input (notese que el input debe tener un ID para que le caiga el valor)
});
});
```

y mi codigo para generar el numero de orden en la variable codigo es donde quiero guardar ese dato

```
<?php       /*Este codigo nos servira para generar un numero diferente para cada ticket*/
      $codigo = ""; 
      $con=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '' );
          mysql_select_db('sisteman');
      $num=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ordenes") or die(mysql_error());
      $numero_filas = mysql_num_rows($num);

      $numero_filas_total=$numero_filas+1;
      $ido="ORD".$codigo."N".$numero_filas_total;

      /*Fin codigo numero de ticket*/?>
```

Comment: creo que te falta codigo y texto en la explicacion, se algo mas preciso para explicar y asi podremos ayudarte con mas agilidad

Comment: Para hacer esto lo mejor es que implementes Ajax desde Javascript, te permitirá enviar el valor al servidor, el cual lo procesará y te devolverá la información requerida para que la presentes en el cliente. Revisa las preguntas relativas a Ajax aquí mismo, hay varias que explican todo el proceso.